# ASP>NET MVC concatenate two details onto dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, concatenation

If I'm using this viewbag

```
ViewBag.employee = (from e in db.Employees
                                    select e.FullName).Distinct();
```

to use in this dropdown list

```
  <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "EmployeeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", new SelectList(ViewBag.employee), "--Select--")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to concatenate on another detail?

For example EmployeesID so that when you use the dropdown list, the EmployeeID will appear beside their name? I need this feature as some employees might have the same name.

Comment: `select e.FullName + " " + e.ID` maybe? And remove the Distinct(). P.S. your dropdown list really ought to be using the ID to identify the selected item anyway. So your SelectList should be passed a list of SelectListItem (these can hold both an ID and a display value) instead of a simple list of strings. That way when the form is submitted back to the server you can be certain exactly which employee was selected.

Comment: Yep!! Post the answer so I can give you credit! :)

Comment: @ADyson Yes I do get an error now that I try to submit!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get what you've asked for is to use

```
select e.FullName + " (" + e.ID + ")"
```

to concatenate the values together at source in the query.

And remove the `Distinct()` as it's unnecessary.

P.S. As a broader point, your dropdown list really ought to be using the ID to identify the selected item anyway. So your SelectList should be passed a list of SelectListItem (these can hold both an ID and a display value) instead of a simple list of strings. That way when the form is submitted back to the server you can be certain exactly which employee was selected. You want Razor to render options like `<option id="2">Joe Bloggs (2)</option>` so that "2" will be the value submitted back to the server. The display value is just for the user and isn't very useful when sending the data back. If you do some searching you'll soon find examples of creating and using SelectListItems.

Comment: so how would I change the dropdown list to use the ID? I'll post the full bit I have to show what I have currently!

Comment: I thought the `EmployeeID` part I have in the dropdown list would be used as the identifier

Comment: no that's just the name of the field. e.g. it will render `<select id="EmployeeID" name="EmployeeID">` based on that. It's not getting any actual Employee ID _values_ from that - they need to come from your query.

Comment: P.S. the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939093/result-of-linq-query-in-mvc-selectlist-as-value-and-text-not-working) will probably help you write your linq query so that it returns a list of SelectListItems to put in the viewbag. Like I said above, you can easily search for how to do this already. Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21940323/5947043) from the same question is arguably a bit easier to comprehend, albeit using Linq-to-entities syntax for the query).